# Magento2 - Magento Headless

Tags: magento2.3, react, headless

Like PWA everyone has started to use the word "`Headless Magento`" but I didn't find anyone to explain it in that detail.

Till now, I only managed to understand that it prefers to use `react` than `knockout js` where it creates a bridge between `Frontend` and `Backend` to load the page even faster but it was all about theory.

Can someone explain it in a proper way with a real example rather than an emphasis on theory?

Answer (score 1):

This article covers it in a simple manner: https://www.coredna.com/blogs/headless-commerce

Comment: Hello Sondre, thanks for sharing a link but it didn't seem that relevant to Magento 2. Again, it was all about theory and pure eCommerce. I want something specific, something precise that could shed the light on Magento2 :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "headless" think of it as "faceless"--in that the backend still exists, but the content is displayed via API (or similar) elsewhere, instead of necessarily on a dedicated, Magento website. It's the marketing *babillage du jour* for a relatively old and unremarkable concept.

Comment: thanks for interest but I need a proper flow, not some random thing or theory :)